# Access Model during Application Error Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 application with error handling setup using Application_Error inside the global.asax.cs file. The error handling itself works fine - I can generate an email with the target url, stack trace and any GET-parameters the user may have passed, but I can't find a way to access POST-values (originally bound to a Model). I've read in a few other questions that POST-values should be available in the Request.Form object, but this object is always empty for me.

Does anyone have any advice on how to get the parameters that were POSTed to a request? Am I going about error handling the wrong way?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use an error handler attribute. In such case you have access to the filterContext which should have everything you need in it.

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute: HandleErrorAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            // do something
        }

        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```